# Let $G=\langle(1,2,3),(1,2)(4,5,6,7)\rangle.$ Find the center of $G$ using a presentation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-presentation

> Let $G=\langle(1,2,3),(1,2)(4,5,6,7)\rangle$ Find the center of $G.$

I find that $G=\langle x,y\mid x^3=y^4=e, xy=yx^2\rangle$. Can I use this presentation to find the center of the group? Is there a better strategy?

EDIT: By direct calculation and some guessing I find the center to be $y^2=(46)(57)$ but I cannot show this rigorously. Please help.

Comment: huh? $(46)(57)$ is not in $\langle (123),(12)(4567)\rangle$.

Comment: Is the square of the second generator no? What I'm calling y.

Comment: Sorry - you are right. I was thinking it was a different exchange.

Comment: $G$ is nonabelian with $|G|=12$ and $|Z(G)|$ divisible by 2. Since $G/|Z(G)$ cannot be cyclic, we must have $|Z(G)|=2$ so $Z(G) = \langle y^2 \rangle$.

Comment: Can you explain why G mod center cannot be cyclic? I have just started group theory, quotient spaces have yet to be formally covered. Edit; I do have some understanding of quotient spaces from linear algebra

Comment: This is a frequently asked question! If $G/Z(G) = \langle xZ(G) \rangle$ is cyclic, then every element of $G$ can be written as $x^iz$ for some $i \in {\mathbb Z}$ and $z \in Z(G)$. But any two elements of that form commute with each other, so $G$ is abelian.